# Why does this built-in type result in an error when compiling?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++

Consider:

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wctype.h>

int main ()
{
  wchar_t c;

  return 0;
}
```

#### Error message

```
In file included from /usr/include/wctype.h:38:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wctype-wchar.h:3:12: error: stray ‘`’ in program
    none of `iswcntrl', `iswdigit', `iswpunct', or `iswspace' is true.  */
            ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wctype-wchar.h:3:36: error: stray ‘`’ in program
    none of `iswcntrl', `iswdigit', `iswpunct', or `iswspace' is true.  */
                                    ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wctype-wchar.h:60:2: error: #endif without #if
 #endif /* bits/wctype-wchar.h.  */
```

OS: [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver)

GCC: 7.5.0

I think *wchar_t* is a standard type... So do I maybe need to update something like GCC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my header file `wctype-wchar.h` was corrupted. I fixed it by reinstalling `libc6-dev`, GCC, and `G++`.